# Unity displays symbols

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encoding

[image: Unity screen]

I write the code in Visual Studio and everything is ok. But in Unity, the code is displayed in symbols. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you post your code? In general: As a software-developer get used to write both code and comments in English .. if we want or not it currently is THE international most common used language for both programming and communication, basically all language keywords are in English and if you ever work in a Team sooner or later you will have a Team member that only speaks English

Comment: If I write the same thing on the Visual Studio Code, then everything is displayed fine!

Comment: Try to change the editor GUI font via [Preferences -> General -> Editor Font](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html#General) and select one that supports your symbols

Comment: @derHugo: there are many reason to put non ASCII code (and ASCII is not enough for good English). Not all programs requires "international" communication; citations requires often other characters; examples and bug titles may requires other characters. Personal TODO also do not require English (and they should be removed before commit. As you see, there are many reasons (and there are more, especially if you work on UI or user inputs) and so we need to be able to display any characters. We are not discussing company coding styles.

Comment: Sorry guys! the text is written in Cyrillic, forgot to clarify.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `and ASCII is not enough for good English` show me one case of good English where that's the case, ASCII is literally ["originally based on the English alphabet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#History) ^^ And for the rest .. why would you care if "personal" (these don't exist in my opinion) todo's and special format const strings are displayed correctly in the Unity preview of the script?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi and I'm not discussing company style but rather a personal opninion. As a serious developer you will use English sooner or later .. so as I said in general get used to it

Comment: @derHugo: check history of ASCII (in more details): there were just 7-bit availables, so they must restrict the characters. there were a lot of discussion on what to include and what not (and original ASCII left few characters free so different systems could still use other characters). `-`, `'`, `"`" have overloaded meaning. Language uses much more acctented letter, it would be naïve to forget it (see the accent?). It lack pound sign, cent sign, degree sign, plus-minus (very frequent in past). US constitution has "fœderal"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://allcorrectgames.com/insights/integrating-text-in-unity/

> The Cyrillic Font Asset should be attached to the Latin Font Asset as
> a fallback, which means it will be used if the game can’t find the
> right character in the main set. And since you can attach any number
> of fallback elements, all the European languages can fit in just a few
> Font Assets!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, the problem is solved!
Everything turned out to be much easier!

Visual Studio
=> Save As
=> Save with encoding
=> UTF8
=> Profit!

[image: Pic]